# Simple Java Scanner Input Incompatible Types

Tags: input

I would like to simply return the amount entered by the user. The user will enter $82 when asked "Amount Given: " and the return will be $82.

An error states that given_amount and return are incompatible types.

Thankyou

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class PartA extends ChangeDrawer 
  {

      public int x (int x)

     {Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

         String given_amount;
         System.out.print("Amount given: ");
          given_amount = input.next( );

        return given_amount;   // Error : given_amount and return are incompatible types 

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you defined has return type `int` so you must return an integer. You are however returning `given_amount` which is a string.

> The data type of the return value must match the method's declared
>   return type;...

See [Returning a Value from a Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html).

In your case, you can either change the method return type to `String`:

```
public String x(int x)    // change return type to String
{
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

    String given_amount;
    given_amount = input.nextLine( );
    System.out.print("Amount given: " + given_amount);

    return given_amount;
}
```

or change `given_amount` to `int`:

```
public int x(int x)
{
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

    int given_amount;    // change given_amount datatype to int
    given_amount = input.nextInt( );
    System.out.print("Amount given: " + given_amount);

    return given_amount;
}
```